# The recently released JDK 7 includes the InvokeDynamic feature. Is it speeding up (and actually used by) Groovy, Scala, Clojure, JRuby, Jython, etc?

Tags: groovy, clojure, jruby, jython, java-7

The recently released JDK 7 includes the long waited InvokeDynamic feature. But are those dynamic languages out there using it? (I mean Groovy, Scala, JRuby, Jython, Clojure, etc)

And more important: at the end of the day we wanna know if there is a performance speedup (yeah it should)

Comment: I'd like to see this question opened again. It is very specific and the already present answer shows that it fits SO.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is invokeDynamic has limited value for Clojure, but can be a strong benefit for other JVM languages. There is a long and very interesting thread about it [here](http://groups.google.com/group/clojure/browse_thread/thread/d66af49bef572e8a/dd82cc60855b1ca3?#dd82cc60855b1ca3).

Comment: Groovy isn't using invokeDynamic yet, either its 1.8.2 or 1.9-beta-3 version. They don't seem to have even started changing their codebase to enable it.

Comment: I know about the benefits. I was just looking for some New compiler for any jvm language that use that feature to see that running in real world